# Seeking free Mexican transportation datasets

Tags: data, transportation, mexico

I have been looking for data of Mexico. What I am looking for is the data of a Transportation in Mexico, specifically Chihuahua province. I have checked out on ArcGIS online and Google but came up nothing good.

Is there one that I overlooked?

I am looking for free gis data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) data via the [OpenStreetMap Loader](http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=15137) for ArcGIS. This [white paper](http://www.esriuk.com/literature/documents/OpenStreetMap%20v12.pdf) from ESRI UK might help as well.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the [VMap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_map) dataset would be of use. This is a global dataset of transportation networks. I'm not sure if your exact area is covered but you can download parts of the dataset from [here](http://gis-lab.info/qa/vmap1-eng.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can also get the OSM data pre-converted to Shapefile and cropped to Mexico or even just Chihuahua from [CloudMade](http://downloads.cloudmade.com/americas/northern_america/mexico). It loses some of the rich tags that in the source data, but may be good enough and has already been converted to an Esri-friendly format.